# Windows 8.1 can't detect my HDD?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have ASUS FX553VD and I'm trying to install win 8.1 but seen like that my win 8.1 can't detect disk.
I tried diskpart command, but can't see any drive online.

Any one know what problem I have ?

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Check the partitions in disk management(right click My computer and choose manage). Check if you find partitions are available without letters, If so right click on that partition and select change driver letter and paths option. Then assign a letter to that partition. This is all, only if you find partitions in the disk management.